# Type mismatch when setting a formula into a cell with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

```
Worksheets("sheet2").Range("C2").Formula = "=AVERAGEIFS(Sheet1!E:E,Sheet1!A:A," >= "&A2,Sheet1!A:A," < "&B2)"
```

I have run the above code in Excel 2007 and I'm getting a

> run time error 13 type mismatch

The above code is used to do average operation from sheet 1 and enter in sheet 2. I request some help in correcting the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you need to escape the quotes with another quote. That means all quotes `"` in the formula become `""`.

If the formula in that cell should be

```
=AVERAGEIFS(Sheet1!E:E,Sheet1!A:A,">=" & A2,Sheet1!A:A,"<" & B2)
```

and you put it into a string between double quotes `" your formula here "`, then you need to escape all quotes within the formula and change a `"` into a `""` like below:

```
Worksheets("sheet2").Range("C2").Formula = _ 
  "=AVERAGEIFS(Sheet1!E:E,Sheet1!A:A,"">="" & A2,Sheet1!A:A,""<"" & B2)"
```

---

Another option would be using the `Chr(34)` instead of a `"`.

```
Worksheets("sheet2").Range("C2").Formula = _ 
  "=AVERAGEIFS(Sheet1!E:E,Sheet1!A:A," & Chr(34) & ">=" & Chr(34) & " & A2,Sheet1!A:A," & Chr(34) & "<" & Chr(34) & " & B2)"
```

This is technically the same but not very human readable in this case.