# VBA Excel IF statement with formula

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to plot the exsiting excel formula into IF statement.

The simple value is not enough, as the formula written before the VBA code is gone.

So I found some way how to plot formula into the code:

https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/writing-formulas-with-macros/

but in order to the situation, as below:

```
If cbleven.Value = True Then
ActiveSheet.Cells(53, 4).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(53, 4).Value - 1
ActiveSheet.Cells(51, 4).Formula = "=C52" + 2
End If
```

I am getting an error: **Type mismatch**

In this event, I must do something different. Another solution can be found here:

[Type mismatch when setting a formula into a cell with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46088338/type-mismatch-when-setting-a-formula-into-a-cell-with-vba)

, regarding to which I prepared my code like this:

```
 Sub CableOddEven()
 Dim cblodd As Range
 Dim wsca As Worksheet
 Dim fm As Formula

 Set wsca = ActiveSheet
 Set cblodd = wsca.Range("C52")

 Set fm = AverageIfs("=C51")
 End If

 If cbleven.Value = True Then
 ActiveSheet.Cells(53, 4).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(53, 4).Value - 1
 ActiveSheet.Cells(51, 4).Value = fm + 2
 'ActiveSheet.Cells(51, 4).Formula = "=C52" + 2
 End If
 End Sub
```

Now the debugger highlights the `Dim fm as Formula`, where an error says: **User-defined type not defined**.

Is there any way to eligible my formula to work with the macro code under the IF condition?

Comment: `"=C52+2"`?????

Comment: When adding a formula the formula is a string: `ActiveSheet.Cells(51, 4).Formula = "=C52 + 2"`

Comment: `Formula` is not a variable type in VBA. So you cannot declare a variable of that type - unless you specifically define the type. What exactly are you trying to do with `Set fm = AverageIfs("=C51")`? Otherwise, see what @ScottCraner said.

Comment: I think, that  @Scott Craner was right. I used their advice and it works :) Thank you all for the help.